# include a menu in some pages

Tags: php, yii

I am working with YII framework and I have made the following, is my inde.php:

[image]

when I click on Dosseirs, I get the following image:

[image]

The problem is that On Dossiers page, the table that includes TABS dosseir/managment info/system beheer, should be in all other pages as well, so from the index when I click on systembeheer I should also be able to see that there.

this is my system beheer:
[image]
as you can see it doesnt contain the TABS previously mentioned. I can go to system beheer page and I can just paste the code of TABS there, and I am able to see the TABS, but its not corret, as I should be able use the code only once and see result in all the pages.

this is what I want I want the TABS to be preented in index.php instead of a list with 3 options. then when I click on dosseirs it should change the title of the page into dosseirs, when I click on managment info it should change the title to that, and finally when I click on systembeheer I should be able to see the title changing to systembeheer and its should include the tabs as usual but inside the system beheer tabs there should be 5 more tabs with different name just like like the TABS we are using.

this is how my approach is :

in my private\protected\views\layouts i have a main.php
and in my private\protected\views\layouts\includes I have footer/header/menu .php

inside my main.php I have:

```
<div id="mainmenu">
        <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
            ),
        )); ?>
    </div><!-- mainmenu -->
```

here is my code for the TABS:

```
<?php 
    $tab1=$this->renderPartial('_tab1', NULL, $return=true);
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiTabs',array(
    'tabs'=>array(
        'Dossier'=>array('content'=>$tab1, 'id'=>'form'),
        'Managment Info'=>array('content'=>'Content for tab 2', 'id'=>'tab2'),
        'Systeem Beheer'=> 'Content for tab 3'
        // panel 3 contains the content rendered by a partial view
    ),
    // additional javascript options for the tabs plugin
    'options'=>array(
        'collapsible'=>true,
    ))); 

?>
```

how can I have tabs in Dosseir/Managment info and system beheer each with its own title?

Answer (score 0):

creata a separate page for the TABS, and render it partialy on other pages.

**tabs.php**

```
<?php 
$tab1=$this->renderPartial('_tab1', NULL, $return=true);
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiTabs',array(
'tabs'=>array(
    'Dossier'=>array('content'=>$tab1, 'id'=>'form'),
    'Managment Info'=>array('content'=>'Content for tab 2', 'id'=>'tab2'),
    'Systeem Beheer'=> 'Content for tab 3'
    // panel 3 contains the content rendered by a partial view
),
// additional javascript options for the tabs plugin
'options'=>array(
    'collapsible'=>true,
))); 
?>
```

Dosseirs.php

```
///This is my Dosseirs page
<?php
  $this->renderPartial('tabs'); //this will render tabs.php
 ?>
```

SystemDesser.php

```
//this is my SystemDesse page
 <?php
  $this->renderPartial('tabs'); //this will render tabs.php
 ?>
```

if you want to render tabs.php with different data for each page, you can pass an extra parameter like below, use that parameter in an if statement inside tabs.php

```
$this->renderPartial('tabs', array('myParam'=>$foo));
```

Comment: how can I do that where should I save the tabs.php and what should I do with _tab page? I have a view for all dosseir/managment info/ system beheer. how many times I need to make the tabs.php?? can u be a little more specific? _tab1 is different for each one of these: dosseir/managment info/ system beheer

Comment: put "tabs.php" inside the same folder as your other views that you want to include it in, as for _tab i don't know what you should do with it, cause i don't even know whats in it.